# Set mount options for removable devices on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, udisks

I share my computer in a multiseat configuration and would like everyone to mount removable devices with a umask of 0 (ie. readable and writeable by all and sundry). Well, ideally just by group *disks* or *plugdev* or something, but global will do in a pinch.

Except nope, it insists on mode 700 with owner and group as my user.

---

Things I thought might work but didn't:

#### Policy kit

This got people able to mount the device. But the permissions were wrong. It does not seem to be possible to change the permissions here---I think only `udisks` can.

#### udev

Tried this rule and didn't manage to get the USB stick. However I'm pretty sure it's moot as this would be the permissions for the device and not the mountpoint and those are already adequate with a gid of *disk*.

```
KERNEL=="sd*[0-9]", ATTR{removable}=="1", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", MODE="0000"
```

#### KDE Device Notifier + udisks

`udisks` performs the mount operation for the KDE Device Notifier. However, it does not have any setting to control/override the mount options it uses. Device Notifier does not seem to have any setting for group or umask either.

However, if one mounts it manually, things work fine. This does anyhow:

```
udisks --mount /dev/sdf1 --mount-options umask=0
```

#### udisks-glue

A very promising tool, but no dice. `udisks-glue` lets your configure custom reactions to `udisks` events on dbus! It can automount devices and you can control the umask for that. Alas this has no effect on the mount options for the Device Notifier and there is no setting to override mount options generally.

It can trigger an event when udisks mounts something. So I thought I'd use it to remount the drive. Except it turns out that while it passes along most mount options just fine, `udisks` cannot handle `remount`.

```
$ udisks --mount /dev/sdf1 --mount-options umask=0,remount
Mount failed: Mount option remount is not allowed
```

---

Aaaand I'm stumped. Any ideas? I'm on 12.10 still, maybe 13.04 has some magic for this?

Comment: I can't get automounting to work on 13.10.:) Maybe the KDE-bits haven't picked up on that user-stuff is to be mounted at /media/<username> now.

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same issue and cannot find any solution

Comment: @skomorokh: Have you gotten a solution ?

Comment: Did you try listing each device by UUID in /etc/fstab with a mountpoint like /media/USB1 with read/write access to your group of users?

Answer (score 2):

The ability to modify the allowed and default mount options is now available in [udisks2](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/) as of version 2.9.0.
Note that you'll need to install a newer version of udisks2 on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 to have access to this functionality.
I wrote up a tutorial on how to install it from source on Ubuntu 18.04 [here](https://www.jwillikers.com/install-udisks2-from-source) for anyone who is interested.
The official udisks2 documentation can be found [here](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/mount_options.html) for how to configure default and allowed mount options.

For your particular use case, you could set the default `vfat` options to include `umask=0` in `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf` as shown here.

```
[defaults]
vfat_defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,shortname=mixed,utf8=1,showexec,flush,umask=0
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option I've found is [udiskie](https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie). Udiskie is in Debian, and thefore also in Ubuntu.

> I share my computer in a multiseat configuration and would like
>   everyone to mount removable devices with a umask of 0 (ie. readable
>   and writeable by all and sundry).

This is what it does by default.

```
udiskie-mount devicename
```

Sample session:

```
udiskie-mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/4E1AEA7B1AEA6007
mounted /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sde1 on /media/faheem/My Passport
cd /media/faheem/My\ Passport
ls -lah
total 302G
drwxrwxrwx  1 faheem faheem 8.0K Apr 19 04:18 .
drwxr-x---+ 3 root   root   4.0K Apr 19 21:08 ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 faheem faheem 4.0K Apr 19 04:19 backup-home
```

If you want to mount with a specific set of permissions, you can do, for example:

```
udiskie-mount -o umask=0022 devicename
```

Sample session:

```
cd ..
udiskie-umount /dev/disk/by-uuid/4E1AEA7B1AEA6007
unmounted /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sde1

cd /media/faheem/My\ Passport
ls -lah
total 302G
drwxr-xr-x  1 faheem faheem 8.0K Apr 19 04:18 .
drwxr-x---+ 3 root   root   4.0K Apr 19 21:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x  1 faheem faheem 4.0K Apr 19 04:19 backup-home
```