# How to force NTFS partition to always be mounted as root?

Tags: mount, fstab, ntfs, automount

I have a system with Windows and Linux installed, and Windows is installed on a driver with an NTFS partition.  I want to make sure that I don't accidentally write to this partition, so I want it always mounted as read-only.

I know I can manually create an /etc/fstab entry to mount that partition at some fixed mount point and have it be read-only.  But that requires me to 1) pick a fixed mount point, and 2) identify the drive manually by UUID or device.

Ubuntu currently mounts that drive dynamically.  It detects the drive and creates a nice mount point.  I want to build on that feature.  Is there a way to tell Ubuntu that *this* particular NTFS device should be mounted read-only, without specifying where it should be mounted or any other mount options.

I tried using the KDE Partition Manager, but it seems to be broken.  It won't actually write any entries to /etc/fstab, even though it says it will.

Comment: Unfortunately, without using the UUIDs we can't set an fstab entry.  And it's pretty simple to get the UUIDs actually.  KDE Partition Manager probably isn't properly running as admin to edit `/etc/fstab`

Comment: KDE Partition Manager does ask for my password when it starts, and it can do everything else.

Comment: But by your own statement, it does NOT add entries to /etc/fstab so either you haven't selected the right option to *write* the mounts to /etc/fstab or it can't because of AppArmor isolation or similar (hence a permissions issue).

Comment: There happens to be a bug filed for it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/partitionmanager/+bug/1873706 and they claim that upstream in version 4.2.0 it has been fixed.

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu you use ?

Comment: Probably writing an udev rule can help you, e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/683881/mount-options-for-udev-rule-mounted-ext3-fs-on14-04-3